# Ênclise com partícula apassivadora e pronome oblíquo

Tags: pronomes-oblíquos

> Regam-se as violetas três vezes por semana. Em relação aos cravos,
>   regam-se-os apenas uma vez por semana.

Na frase acima, gostaria de utilizar a ênclise com "se" e "os". Essa estrutura existe em Português? Ou só me resta a opção de reescrever as frases para algo como "são regados apenas uma vez por semana"?

Comment: Gosto do tipo e qualidade das tuas contribuições. :)

Comment: @ANeves, obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com o sítio [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/novamente-a-combinacao-dos-pronomes-se-e-o/33994), do Instituto Universitário de Lisboa, essa estrutura não existe. Algumas alternativas são:

- "Em relação aos cravos, regam-se apenas uma vez por semana."
- "Em relação aos cravos, regam-se eles apenas uma vez por semana."